# Gitlab CI run job when MR is merged

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've been reviewing the gitlab CI docs and can not find anything on how to run a Job when I merge the branch.

Let's say I have a MR where the source branch is `feature-1` and I am merging this into `master`.

Once the branch is merged I want a job to run. Here is what I've tried:

```
after_merge:
  stage: after_merge
  image: my_image
  only:
    - master
    - merge_requests
  script:
    - ls
    # more of the script
```

This job runs when I create the MR but when I merge this MR nothing is happening to master, so I am not sure why it ran.

What I need is this job to run after I merge the code, I have been reviewing this https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic and this https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/index.html but can't figure it out.

Comment: By default a pipeline runs when merging

Answer (score 0):

Your pipeline will run when one of the following two triggers are triggered:

1. You open a merge request (**independently** of the source and target branches of the MR).
2. You push directly into or merge into the `master` branch.

Comment: that‘s true, but I want to get mr title when merge success on master, in a normal pipeline not a merge_requests pipeline. do you know how to do that?